# Flutter : Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

Tags: flutter, admob

I am relative new to Flutter.After playing around with adding ads to my app (emulator implementation so far - using firebase admod plugin - latest version), the console keeps spawning the following message

**Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread**

Firstly, I considered as a warning of something. However, the app's performance keeps decreasing and sometimes causing some services to fail.I made an apk build  in order to test the behavior at a mobile, but still I haven't seen any ads in order to see any performance hiccups (newly subscribed to admob so it take some time to serve ads). When I remove completely all the code for the ads the performance comes back to its standards.

Another strange thing is that when I use the

> adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,

it gives me the same message 4-5 times and then stops. However, with real adUnitId keeps logging the same message over and over again.

I saw related subjects, but none of them referring to Flutter.

I would appreciate any advice. Probably, I do something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A first-party plugin [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) has been recently launched and the Flutter team recommends using this plugin going forward.